# Usage of "As ..." in the beginning of a sentence, Any alternatives?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I use the following type of sentences a lot, because I do not know any alternatives:

E.g.

> **As** my child grows over time, I become older.

By which I mean that I my child is growing, and I am getting older, and this is a constant process.

What are the alternative ways to express such things?

Thanks!

Comment: Your first question is a very basic grammar question, and the answer is _yes_. Verbs in the third person singular take _-s_ (except modal verbs). There are several ways of expressing simultaneous/parallel actions/processes like this one, but _as X happens, Y (also) happens_ is perfectly fine and very idiomatic, so you don’t _need_ to use any alternative ways.

Comment: Thank you! However, sometimes I seek more prestigious styles for academic papers, specially for longer questions (when X and Y are long).

Answer (score 1):

You could replace “As” with “When” or “While”. 
Another structure is “*X* and *Y*  happen [or **occur**]
concurrently [or **simultaneously**, but that doesn’t mean *exactly* the same thing]”.

Answer (score 0):

"I age in proportion to my child's development over time".

Comment: This is mathematically incorrect, since your child’s age doubles between his first and second birthdays, but the same is not true for you (although it may feel like it!).

Comment: @Scott-СлаваУкраїні A thing can have more than one characteristic. It can be both +1 and doubled, which means it can be both proportional and not at the same time.